# Laravel5 MessageBag keys and input names arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

working with a Laravel 5 project, I'm trying to use my custom Request class for validation, and I have a form with several inputs which name's are arrays. Example input :

```
<input name="en[title]" type="text">
```

However, in the Request class, I must declare the rule for the input above as:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'en.title' => 'required|min:3',
  ];
}
```

This works fine, and I can cycle through the `$errors` variable in my view, without a problem. 
However, if I want to use some extended library to match the input names to the errors in the `MessageBag`, and display them nicely inline (below each form input), since the `MessageBag` keys do not match... I can't.

Is there a way to post process the error bag? Or maybe alias the error bag keys?

The only solution I can come up with, is to cycle through the `$errors` in my view, check for the desired key-key translation, and do that manually. But I find this very anti-laravelesque.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if thats what your looking for but the message bag has `first` and `get` methods,they work the same - you give them the name of the field and you will get the error(s) [might be multiple errors for the `get` method] [Laravel 5 form validation - Working With Error Messages](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#working-with-error-messages)

Comment: Well, not so much. I can get the errors easily. But my problem is that the actual name of the field is `en[title]` and the key in the error bag is `en.title`. So I don't see a way to automate error retrieval in this scenario. :(

Comment: Why cant you automate this using regex ? or I just cant see whats the real issue here..

Comment: Yes. My question would be where is the best place to do this, since I feel the view is not the proper place. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this in the request object. After validation put the your key with the validation message in the messages array.